# Create Taxonomy term with added text and date fields, then display them in "add content"

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'd like to add a date field ("date") and a text field ("notes") to a taxonomy term ("Category").  Easy enough.

When I add content, I have the taxonomy term linked using term reference, and it is working fine.

What I can't figure out is this: I'd like the "date" and "notes" field to also appear on the add content screen once the "Category" is selected, and be fully editable.  How would I go about this?

Specifically, when I add content, I select the category and enter all other relevant data. I then enter a date and notes that apply to that node being created, and also apply to any other node of the same category.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with any contributed module which will server your requirement.
But i can help you to achieve this functionality.

Add the Date and Notes field to the specific content type using the '**Add Existing field**' option. Since you have already created the fields for taxonomy term, its not necessary to create a new fields.

While adding a new content of that particular content type, mention the category , date and notes in the respective fields.

Now what we need to do is to hack-into the node submit flow and update the specific taxonomy term with the newly entered date and notes values.

Easily do this by using a single hook : [hook_node_presave($node)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

You can using this hook in any of the custom module. The '$node' variable will contain the date and notes values. We can easily load the selected taxonomy and update the date and notes of the taxonomy via DB queries

Thanks,
Vineeth

Comment: Vineeth, thanks for the quick help. I've been poking around but am unable to follow your directions. Sorry I'm a bit of a noob in code hacking! I'm guessing I need to add this to node.pages.inc, but not sure how/where? Would you be able to tell me a bit more? Thanks again, and sorry for the additional request!!

Answer (score 0):

we should create a custom module. Please follow these steps:

---

Step 1: Create a folder named '**mytweeks**' inside '/sites/all/modules' folder

---

Step 2: Create 2 files [**mytweeks.info** and **mytweeks.module**] inside the 'mytweeks' folder

---

Step 3: Add the following lines inside mytweeks.info file and save it:

```
name = My Tweeks
description = "This module is to tweek my node actions"
core = 7.x
```

Step 4: Add the following lines inside mytweeks.module file and save it.

```
function mytweeks_node_presave($node){

/*
The $node variable will contain all the submitted node form values.
Extract the 'date' and 'notes' values from $node variable. 
Below this comment, write your PHP-MYSQL logic to update those values to the respective taxonomy term field. 
This function will be invoke whenever you submit a content/node add form.
*/

}
```

Hope this helped.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Vineeth for the additional info, I'll follow your your directions above and see if I can get it to work!